# Trying to make string array passed through methods C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to read names and ages from user, until user inputs "stop". Then just print all these values. Please help me , I'm just the beginner in C++

```
// Pass.cpp
// Reading names and ages from user and outputting them

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::strcmp;

char** larger(char** arr);
int* larger(int* arr);
void read_data(char*** names, int** ages);
void print_data(char*** names, int** ages);

int main()
{
    char** names = new char*[5];
    char*** p_names = &names;
    int* ages = new int[5];
    int** p_ages = &ages;
    read_data(p_names,p_ages);
    print_data(p_names,p_ages);
}

void read_data(char*** names, int** ages)
{
    const char* sent = "stop";
    const int MAX = 15;
    int count = 0;
    char UI[MAX];

    cout << "Enter names and ages."
        << endl << "Maximum length of name is " << MAX
        << endl << "When stop enter \"" << sent << "\".";

    while (true)
    {
        cout << endl << "Name: ";
        cin.getline(UI,MAX,'\n');

        if (!strcmp(UI, sent))
            break;
        if (count + 1 > sizeof (&ages) / sizeof (&ages[0]))
        {
            *names = larger(*names);
            *ages = larger(*ages);
        }

        *names[count] = UI;

        cout << endl << "Age: ";
        cin >> *ages[count++];
    }
}

void print_data(char*** names, int** ages)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*ages) / sizeof(*ages[0]);i++)
    {
        cout << endl << setw(10) << "Name: " << *names[i]
            << setw(10) << "Age: " << *ages[i];
    }
}

char** larger(char** names)
{
    const int size = sizeof(names) / sizeof(*names);
    char** new_arr = new char*[2*size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new_arr[i] = names[i];
    return new_arr;
}

int* larger(int* ages)
{
    const int size = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(*ages);
    int* new_arr = new int[2 * size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new_arr[i] = ages[i];
    return new_arr;
}
```

Comment: Edit your post and add your code.

Comment: How ? Code is huge and I got error from stackoverflow to edit it.
How to edit ?

Comment: Most probably you want to use `std::string&` for [tag:c++].

Comment: @user3290289 If the code is huge, you can cut large parts of. It's way easier to help you if your question only contains a small example that replicates the problem.

Comment: @user3290289 _'How ?'_ Make a [SCCEE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problems.

Comment: But I dont know where I have bug :(

Comment: Congratulations on your *three-star programming*.

Comment: _'But I don't know where I have bug :('_ Use a debugger then, we aren't such!

Comment: Can anyone solve bug without using just pointers ?

Comment: This code is what Stroustrup would call "ghastly style" Why are you trying to shoot yourself in the leg? ( Why are you using double/triple `*` ? )

Comment: `sizeof(*ages) / sizeof(*ages[0])` - You seem to think pointers are the same as arrays. Get that notion out of your head. It only furthers the damage done by using pointers in the first place.

Comment: @olevegard what's the better way ?

Comment: An instant improvement is using references for modified parameters, and then there's `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: As a beginner, learn to search first.  For example, search StackOverflow for "c++ read file parse"

Comment: I'm following c++ book I haven't learned yet std::string and std::vector, so the problem is next:
    Write a program that reads a number (an integer) and a name (less than 15 characters) from the keyboard. Design the program so that the data is done in one function, and the output in another. Store the data in the main() function. The program should end when zero is entered for the number. Think about how you are going to pass the data between functions - by value, by pointer, or by reference ?

Comment: So i made it little bit harder :D

Comment: @Jefffrey Congratulations on your three-f name ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really over complicating things.

Given the original problem:

> Write a program that reads a number (an integer) and a name (less than
>   15 characters) from the keyboard. Design the program so that the data
>   is done in one function, and the output in another. Store the data in
>   the main() function. The program should end when zero is entered for
>   the number. Think about how you are going to pass the data between
>   functions

The problem wants you to think about passing parameters to functions. A simple solution would be:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Pass in a char array and an integer reference.
// These values will be modified in the function
void read_data(char name[], int& age)
{
    cout << endl << "Age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl << "Name: ";
    cin.getline(name, 16);
}

// Pass a const array and an int value
// These values will not be modified
void print_data(char const *name, int age)
{
    cout << endl << setw(10) << "Name: " << name
            << setw(10) << "Age: " << age;
}
int main()
{
    char name[16];
    int age;

    cout << "Enter names and ages."
        << endl << "Enter 0 age to quit.";

    do {
            read_data(name, age);
        print_data(name, age);
    } while (0 != age)
}
```

EDIT: Modified per user3290289's comment

EDIT2: Storing data in an array

```
// Simplify by storing data in a struct (so we don't have to manage 2 arrays)
struct Person {
    char name[16];
    int age;
};

// Returns how many People were input
int read_data(Person*& arr)
{
    int block = 10; // How many persons to allocate at a time
    arr = NULL;
    int arr_size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (index == arr_size) {
            arr_size += block;
            arr = (Person *)realloc(arr, arr_size * sizeof(Person)); // Reallocation
            // Should check for error here!
        }
        cout << endl << "Age: ";
        cin >> arr[index].age;
        cin.ignore();
        if (0 == arr[index].age) {
            return index;
        }
        cout << endl << "Name: ";
        cin.getline(arr[index++].name, 16);
    }
}

void print_data(Person *arr, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << endl << setw(10) << "Name: " << arr[i].name
            << setw(10) << "Age: " << arr[i].age;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Person *arr;

    int count = read_data(arr);
    print_data(arr, count);
    free(arr);  // Free the memory
}
```

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to store all names/ages. So my update is not what you want...Without using STL (vector), you can create a simple linked list. Or use arrays, but you have to be prepared to re-size the arrays as you don't know ahead of time how many names will be entered.

Comment: @user3290289 Ok, modified again to store data in an array.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work :), It works nice.
I'll find out later how `realloc` and `struct` works. I think I made things over complicated :D I'v been coding in java and i know this is really very easy task, so i tried to do it on "low level" :DD

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::strcmp;

void read_data(std::vector<std::string> &names, std::vector<int> &ages);
void print_data(std::vector<std::string> &names, std::vector<int> &ages);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<int> ages;

    read_data(names, ages);
    print_data(names, ages);
}

void read_data(std::vector<std::string> &names, std::vector<int> &ages)
{
    const char* sent = "stop";

    cout << "Enter names and ages."
        << endl << "When stop enter \"" << sent << "\".";

    while (true)
    {
        std::string input;
        cout << endl << "Name: ";
        std::getline(cin, input);

        if (!strcmp(input.c_str(), sent))
            break;
        names.push_back(input);

        cout << endl << "Age: ";
        std::string age;
        std::getline(cin, age);

        ages.push_back(atoi(age.c_str()));
    }
}

void print_data(std::vector<std::string> &names, std::vector<int> &ages)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.capacity() ; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << setw(10) << "Name: " << names.at(i)
            << setw(10) << "Age: " << ages.at(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is this if statement:

```
if (count + 1 > sizeof (&ages) / sizeof (&ages[0]))
```

&ages is the address of an int**, a pointer, and so it's size is 8 (usually) as that is the size of a pointer type. The function does not know the size of the array, sizeof will only return the correct answer when ages is declared in the same scope.

```
sizeof(&ages) / sizeof(&ages[0])
```

will always return 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe one natural solution about this problem is as follows:

1. create a "std::map" instance. Here std::map would sort the elements according to the age. Here my assumption is after storing the data into the container, you would like to find about a particular student age/smallest/largest and all various manipulation with data.Just storing and printing the data does not make much sense in general.
2. create a "std::pair" and take the both input from the user into the std::pair "first" and "second" member respectively. Now you can insert this "std::pair" instance value into the above "std::map" object.
3. While printing, you can now fetch the each element of "std::map" in the form of "std::pair" and then you can display pair "first" and "second" part respectively.